# How to set TXT SPF DNS records in AWS Route53 using CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53, spf

I am using AWS CloudFormation to manage my site DNS records in AWS Route53. To define the SPF records, up until now I have been using the following template snippet:

```yaml
RecordSetGroup:
  Type: "AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup"
  Properties:
    HostedZoneId: !Ref HostedZone
    RecordSets:
      - Name: !Sub '${DomainName}.'
        TTL: 3600
        Type: SPF
        ResourceRecords:
          - '"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"'
      - Name: !Sub '*.${DomainName}.'
        TTL: 3600
        Type: SPF
        ResourceRecords:
          - '"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"'
```

I've read in several places that the SPF DNS record type is deprecated and that TXT records should be used instead to advertise SPF info (including in the [CloudFormation documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-recordset.html#cfn-route53-recordset-type)). So I tried the following CloudFormation snippet instead:

```yaml
RecordSetGroup:
  Type: "AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup"
  Properties:
    HostedZoneId: !Ref HostedZone
    RecordSets:
      - Name: !Sub '${DomainName}.'
        TTL: 3600
        Type: TXT
        ResourceRecords:
          - '"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"'
      - Name: !Sub '*.${DomainName}.'
        TTL: 3600
        Type: TXT
        ResourceRecords:
          - '"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"'
```

But when I try to update my stack using this template I get the following error from CloudFormation:

```
UPDATE_FAILED [The request contains an invalid set of changes for a resource record set 'TXT domain.com.', The request contains an invalid set of changes for a resource record set 'TXT \052.domain.com.']
```

Any idea why CloudFormation is unhappy with these TXT records?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4):

I found my mistake. I already had other TXT records with the same name. So instead of adding more TXT records, I merged them into single records with multiple values and that worked:

```yaml
RecordSetGroup:
  Type: "AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup"
  Properties:
    HostedZoneId: !Ref HostedZone
    RecordSets:
      - Name: !Sub '${DomainName}.'
        TTL: 3600
        Type: TXT
        ResourceRecords:
          - '"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"'
          - '"google-site-verification=..."'
      - Name: !Sub '*.${DomainName}.'
        TTL: 3600
        Type: TXT
        ResourceRecords:
          - '"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"'
          - '"google-site-verification=..."'
```